# Problems with preg_replace, obtaining $1

Tags: php, function

I'm using this code to get LINK and put the url in it, however the makelink function is not working, how can I pass the resulting $1 to the function?

```
$parsedMessage = preg_replace(array('/(?i)\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?´ªìîëí]))/'), array(''.$this->makelink($1).''), $message);
```

Comment: `$1` isn't a variable.  It's used in the replacement string.  If you want to pass it to a function, you need to use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) instead.

Comment: I am ignorant of the language, how do I transition?